# integral representation

Tags: calculus

I try find integral representation to following function ($d_1<d_2$ and $d_2-d_1=1(\mod 2)$
$f( d_1,d_2)=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{d_2-d_1-1}{2}}}{2^{d_1-1} d_1!}\sum_{k=[\frac{d_1}{2}]+1}^{ d_1} { d_1 \choose k}\frac{ (2k-d_1)^{d_1+d_2-2}}{ (d_2{+}d_1{-}2k)!! (d_2{-}d_1{+}2k)!!}-\frac{1}{ 2^{d_2-1}d_2!}\sum_{  k=0}^{ [\frac{d_2}{2}]}{ d_2 \choose k}\frac{(-1)^k (d_2-2k)^{d_1+d_2-2}} {\prod_{i=0}^{d_1} (d_2-d_1-2k+2i)}.$

Here are some attempts:
$$f(d_1,d_2)=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{d_2-d_1-1}{2}}}{2^{d_1-1} d_1!}\sum_{k=0}^{ d_1} { d_1 \choose k} {\rm sign}(\frac{d_2}{2}-k)\frac{ (2k-d_1)^{d_1+d_2-2}}{ (d_2{+}d_1{-}2k)!! (d_2{-}d_1{+}2k)!!}-\frac{1}{ 2^{d_2-1}d_2!}\sum_{  k=0}^{ d_2}{ d_2 \choose k}{\rm sign}(k-\frac{d_1}{2})\frac{(-1)^k (d_2-2k)^{d_1+d_2-2}} {\prod_{i=0}^{d_1} (d_2-d_1-2k+2i)}=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{d_2-d_1-1}{2}}2}{2^{d_1-1} d_1!\pi}\sum_{0}^{ d_1} { d_1 \choose k}\displaystyle \int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\sin (k-\frac{d_1}{2}) x}}{x}  dx\frac{ (2k-d_1)^{d_1+d_2-2}}{ (d_2{+}d_1{-}2k)!! (d_2{-}d_1{+}2k)!!}-\frac{2}{ 2^{d_2-1}d_2!\pi}\sum_{  k=0}^{d_2}{ d_2 \choose k}\frac{(-1)^k (d_2-2k)^{d_1+d_2-2}} {\prod_{i=0}^{d_1} (d_2-d_1-2k+2i)}\displaystyle \int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\sin (\frac{d_2}{2}-k) x}}{x}  dx=\displaystyle \int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\rm{Im}(\frac{(-1)^{\frac{d_2-d_1-1}{2}}}{2^{d_1-2} d_1!\pi}\sum_{0}^{ d_1} { d_1 \choose k}e^{(k-\frac{d_1}{2}) x}\frac{ (2k-d_1)^{d_1+d_2-2}}{ (d_2{+}d_1{-}2k)!! (d_2{-}d_1{+}2k)!!}-\frac{1}{ 2^{d_2-2}d_2!\pi}\sum_{  k=0}^{d_2}{ d_2 \choose k}\frac{(-1)^k (d_2-2k)^{d_1+d_2-2}} {\prod_{i=0}^{d_1} (d_2-d_1-2k+2i)}e^{ (\frac{d_2}{2}-k) x})\frac{dx}{x}.$$
I use that 
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}\, {\rm sign}(a)=\displaystyle \int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\sin a x}}{x}  dx
$$
This is my attempt so far. But In  Springer, T.A., Invariant theory.  Lecture Notes in Mathematics. 585., Springer-Verlag.  (1977), 111 p. (Lemma 3.4.7) there is analogous function. Author considers function $$c_d:=\deg(\mathcal{C}_d) \cdot \, d!=\sum_{0 \leq j  < d/2} (-1)^j { d \choose j}\left( \frac{d}{2}-j \right)^{d-1}$$ 
\begin{gather*}
\sin ^d\frac{x}{2}=\left(\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{2}}-e^{-\frac{ix}{2}}}{2i}\right)^d=
 \frac{1}{2^d i^d}\sum_{j=0}^d  { d \choose j}\left(e^{\frac{ix}{2}}\right)^{d-j}\left(e^{-\frac{ix}{2}}\right)^j=
   \frac{1}{2^d i^d}\sum_{j=0}^ d (-1)^j { d \choose e}e^{ix(\frac{d}{2}-j)}.
 \end{gather*}
Differentiating $d-1$ times with respect to $x$ he obtains
$$
\left(\sin ^d\frac{x}{2}\right)^{(d-1)}= \frac{i^{d-1}}{2^d i^d}\sum_{0 \leq e  \leq d} (-1)^e { d \choose j} \left(\frac{d}{2}-j\right)^{d-1}e^{ix(\frac{d}{2}-j)}.
$$
Hence 
$$
{\rm Im} \left(\sum_{j=0}^d (-1)^j { d \choose j}\left( \frac{d}{2}-j \right)^{d-1}e^{i( \frac{d}{2}-j )x}\right)=2^d  \left(\sin ^d\frac{x}{2}\right)^{(d-1)}.
$$

```
Thus
```

$$ c_d= \frac{1}{\pi } \int \limits _{0}^{\infty}2^d\left(\sin ^d\frac{x}{2}\right)^{(d-1)}\frac{dx}{x}=
      \frac{2}{\pi } \int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\left(\sin ^d x\right)^{(d-1)}\frac{dx}{x}
$$
    Integrating by parts $d-1$ times he obtains
    $$ c_d=\frac{2(d-1)!}{\pi} \displaystyle \int \limits _{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\sin ^d x}}{x^d}  dx, $$

But I have $(d_2{+}d_1{-}2k)!! (d_2{-}d_1{+}2k)!!$ and $\prod_{i=0}^{d_1} (d_2-d_1-2k+2i)$ in the denominators. I can not do it
Help me.

This  question I published on the MathOverFlow too. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184489/integral-representation-of-the-function